# All rows in one dataframe substracts another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID,   A, B, C, D
111   0, 1, 2, 3
222   2, 3, 4, 5
333   3, 4, 5, 6
```

and a row

```
A, B, C, D
0, 1, 0, 1
```

I want every row in the first dataframe minus the row in the above, and do not affect the ID column. The expect result is

```
ID,   A, B, C, D
111   0, 0, 2, 2
222   2, 2, 4, 4
333   3, 3, 5, 5
```

I don't know the best way to implement this. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subsetting `df1` from `df2` columns to apply subtraction:

```
df1[df2.columns] = df1[df2.columns] - df2.values

# Or suggested by @mozway
df1[df2.columns] = df1[df2.columns].sub(df2.loc[0], axis=1)

print(df1)

# Output
    ID  A  B  C  D
0  111  0  0  2  2
1  222  2  2  4  4
2  333  3  3  5  5
```

Input:

```
>>> df1
    ID  A  B  C  D
0  111  0  1  2  3
1  222  2  3  4  5
2  333  3  4  5  6

>>> df2
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: Other option; `df1[df2.columns].sub(df2.loc[0], axis=1)`